# Why is Razor ignoring the '@' keyword escape symbol?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

All of a sudden (I made no major changes), the IDE and Razor compiler doesn't recognise C# keywords escaped by `@`, like `class` is highlighted in yellow in the below image:

[image]

It's well worth noting that just isn't a mere syntax highlighting problem, as the code doesn't compile either, and the compiler gives the following error for the code snippet above:

> "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.
>   An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.

Comment: You need to remove `<>` after `LabelFor` and `EditorFor`.

Comment: Thanks, @ChetanRanpariya. I don't know where those came from, some sort of IDE Texas Massacre or something. I have removed all of then.

Comment: Can someone with guts enough to put their name behind it tell me why this question is off-topic?

Comment: Do you use R#? Have you tried to close and re-open solution?

Comment: @JoãoPereira I do use R#, but it never made VS turn a false compile error. I've tried re-opening the solution, Visual Studio, and rebooting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.SomekingStatus, new { @class = "col-md-2 control label"}) 
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Value ,new{@class="form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Value)
    </div>
 </div>
```